# Ordenar tabelas do HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, table, classificação

Eu tenho 2 tabelas que foram inicializadas no HTML mas que vai juntando linhas e colunas através de 2 funções Javascript.

HTML Tabela 1:

```
<table id="myTable" >
  <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>Disciplina</th>
    <th>Prioridade</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML Tabela 2:

```
<table id="myTable2">
  <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>Disciplina</th>
    <th>Método de avaliação</th>
    <th>Data da avaliação</th>
    <th>Antecedência</th>
    <th>Duração por dia</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
     //Tabela 1 
    ...
    var array = localStorage.getItem("ListaDisciplinas").split(','); // lista de disciplinas
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var a = document.getElementById( "mySelect" + i);
        var valor1 = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;
        localStorage.setItem("Prioridade" + array[i],valor1);
        localStorage.setItem("Disciplinas" + i,array[i]);
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Disciplinas" + i);
        cell2.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Prioridade" + array [i]);
}
    ...


        // tabela 2
      ...
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable2");
                var row = table.insertRow(1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                cell1.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("disciplinas");
                cell2.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("metododeavaliaçao");
                cell3.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Data");
                cell4.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("DiasAtecedencia");
                cell5.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("duraçaopordia");
                  ...
```

O que pretendo é ordenar ,com Javascript ou Jquery , a Tabela 1 alfabeticamente  pelo nome das disciplinas , primeiro coluna e ordenar a Tabela 2 pela data , terceira coluna

Comment: Você consulta essas informações de algum banco de dados? não seria mais fácil ordenar no `sql`?

Comment: As tabelas estão a ser usadas numa página HTML e para ordenar só posso usar mesmo ou Javascript ou Jquery

Comment: como é que está definida a variável `i`?

Comment: já coloquei o código todo correcto

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `sort` do `array`:

> **[Sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp):**
>
> O método `sort()` organiza os itens de um `array`.

*Ordenar pelo nome das disciplinas:*

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
  if(a.disciplinas < b.disciplinas) {
    return -1;
  }

  if(a.disciplinas > b.disciplinas) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
})
```

*Ordenar pela data das disciplinas:*

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.Data) - new Date(a.Data);
});
```

Comment: @Srack , boa noite, utilizando .sort é possivel fazer um algoritmo de ordenação com prioridade  ?